# Keeping P Element Inside A Div

Tags: html, css

I would like to make this div responsive and keep the text in the center of it the entire time. As of now, it looks fine on mobile since I added media queries to it, but on desktop the p element in my .info-p-div goes into the div below and looks awful. These divs are side-by-side on the page. I will post my HTML and CSS code relating to this section of the page so you can see what I mean.

HTML

```
<div class="info">
<div class="info-img-div">
<img src="images/owner.jpg" />
<p><font color="#F5F5F5">Text here</font></p>
</div>
<div class="info-p-div">
<p><font color="#F5F5F5">Text here</font></p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="parallax-3"></div>
```

CSS

```
.info   {
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
}

.info-img-div   {
    position: left;
    width: 35%;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.info-img-div img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 25%;
    width: 25%;
    min-height: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.info-p-div {
    height: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 65%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.parallax-3 {
    background-image: url("images/background3.jpg");
    height: 400px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)   {
    .info   {
        text-align: center;
        float: none;
        height: 50%;
    }
    .info-img-div   {
        float: none;
        border-right-style: none;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .info-p-div {
        float: none;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can get it by `flex`

Comment: I tried that before, but the p was still sticking out from the div. :(

Comment: @James Hammond please provide a [Complete, Minimal, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  You have not provided any code regarding the "div below" that you mention in OP.  It is difficult to assist without having the code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @McHat it is done!

Comment: @JamesHammond check answer may be it will help you.

Comment: @LKG I was referring to the answer you gave me. Yes, it works in your example but it's not working for my site. One difference is that I have two divs that need to display on the same vertical level while on desktop mode. They stack onto each other when the screen size shrinks as you see from my code, they look nice there, but on desktop the paragraph on the .info-p-div leaks into the div below them.

Comment: @LKG I figured it out, mate. Thank you so much for your help, greatly appreciated! Your solution worked after all, I can tell I have been coding for 9 hours; eyes are tired. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for below solution.

I posted an working example.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: tomato;
}

.box p {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .box {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .box p {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this before and it does make the text center nicely. However, it still goes into the .parallax-3 div. I just tried it again on the site. It does work in your example though. I am guessing my issue relates to the fact that this div needs to take up 75% of the width while the one next to it takes up 25% until they go mobile via media query. See my code above for reference. Thanks again! @LKG